# How do I achieve secure inter-node communication in a distributed cluster in the Play Framework for Java?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, distributed-computing, distributed

My application is based on the Play Framework for Java. I'm making it distributed by simply deploying the same application onto multiple servers and distributing the web requests accordingly between them. Each node will be connected to the same database.

The Play Framework already uses Netty, so I have the option of using HTTP requests for communication between nodes, but I am unsure how to secure some of these requests, so that some of them can be called from a browser, i.e. the website I'm using the framework for can still call certain routes / api endpoints, while some routes / api endpoints are restricted and can only be called by other nodes in the cluster, so that nodes can communicate between each other.

Here is an example controller which I want to be accessible publicly

```
public class TestController extends Controller {
  public static Result create() {
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
    if (json == null) return badRequest("Invalid JSON!");

    Testmodel model = JsonHelper.fromJson(json.toString(), Testmodel.class);
    if (model == null) return badRequest("JSON does not conform to model!");

    MongoHelper.getInstance().getDatastore().save(model);

    return ok(JsonHelper.toJson(model));
  }

  public static Result addOneTest() {
    Testmodel somemodel = new Testmodel();
    somemodel.setName("name" + Math.random());
    somemodel.setValue("val" + Math.random());

    MongoHelper.getInstance().getDatastore().save(somemodel);

    return ok(JsonHelper.toJson(somemodel));
  }

  public static Result getAllTest() {
    List<Testmodel> all = MongoHelper.getInstance().getDatastore().find(Testmodel.class).asList();
    return ok(JsonHelper.toJson(all));
  }

  public static Result getCountTest() {
    long count = MongoHelper.getInstance().getDatastore().getCount(Testmodel.class);
    return ok(Long.toString(count));
  }

  public static Result deleteAllTest() {
    Datastore ds = MongoHelper.getInstance().getDatastore();
    WriteResult result = ds.delete(ds.createQuery(Testmodel.class));

    return ok(JsonHelper.toJson(result));
  }
}
```

And here are the example routes / api endpoints for this controller

```
POST    /api/test/create                    controllers.TestController.create()
POST    /api/test/add                       controllers.TestController.addOneTest()
DELETE  /api/test/delete                    controllers.TestController.deleteAllTest()
GET     /api/test/get                       controllers.TestController.getAllTest
GET     /api/test/count                     controllers.TestController.getCountTest
```

And here is an example of a controller I do **not** want publicly accessible, i.e. I want only the nodes in the cluster to be able to use it so they can talk to each other via HTTP requests and run certain methods from another node or pass data to another node. The restriction on public accessibility is obvious for security purposes, I do not want people from the website accessing any of the routes for this controller.

```
public class NodeController extends Controller {
  public static Result runJob(ObjectId jobId) {
    Submission submission = MongoHelper.getInstance().getDatastore().get(Submission.class, jobId);
    if (submission == null) {
      return badRequest("No job with that id");
    }
    // TODO Do some more error checking and validation on the submission

    JobRunner.getInstance().run(jobId);
    return ok();
  }

  public static Result cancelJob(ObjectId jobId) {
    boolean cancelled = JobRunner.getInstance().cancel(jobId);
    if (cancelled) return ok();
    else return badRequest("Example error");
  }
}
```

The only option I could find for securing these is using the [Play Framework's Allowed Hosts Filters](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AllowedHostsFilter), which makes the framework accept HTTP requests only from specified hosts, but the problem is this applies a blanket filter, i.e. all requests will be restricted, even those which I want to be accessible publicly.

Another option I read about is Java Remote Method Invocation (RMI), but I am a beginner so it might be a bit hard for me. The project is also fairly small and simple, so I'm concerned this may be overkill. As you can see in the examples above (Particularly the NodeController), all I need is for nodes to call one or two lines of code from another node potentially.

## EDIT

I managed to restrict a given controller only to preconfigured source addresses using Action Composition like so:

```
public class SourceAddressFilter extends Action<SourceAddressFilter> {
  private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = play.Logger.underlying();
  private static final List<String> allowedAddresses =
          Configuration.root().getStringList("nodes.allowedSourceAddresses");

  @Override
  public CompletionStage<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) {
    String srcAddress = ctx.request().remoteAddress();

    if (!allowedAddresses.contains(srcAddress)) {
      LOGGER.error("Address {} attempted to perform action, but is not in the list of allowed hosts!", srcAddress);
      return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(badRequest("Address " + srcAddress + " is not authorized!"));
    }

    return delegate.call(ctx);
  }
}
```

Then adding the following annotation at the start of each controller:

```
@With(SourceAddressFilter.class)
```

It works, though I am a bit concerned about how good of a method this is and if it's possible to somehow either fake this in a request or simply receive the wrong one by calling request().remoteAddress() in the Action.

I would still be interested to know if it's possible to be done using JWT as suggested in the answers, but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [JWT](https://jwt.io/) and manage your authentication with tokens + an [action composition](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaActionsComposition#Composing-actions).

JWT allows you to create signed tokens that you can share between your applications.

Comment: That definitely looks like something useful. It's probably better than somehow filtering by hosts or IP. I just learned how to do action composition, so I'll just need to figure out how JWT works. Any tips on how exactly to use it or which of the libraries for Java listed on that website are good?

Comment: I've updated my question with the Action I made for remote address filtering. How would I update that to work with JWT? It seems JWT is mostly about sending secure payloads, though I don't really want to do that, I just want to restrict certian API's from being called by the wrong people. If all JWT does is encryption, then isn't it possible for someone to intercept the HTTP request and submit an identical one, even if they won't know what will happen and my app will accept it? It's important for it to not receive any duplicate requests.